# I get "Process can not access the file...." error while deleting the FILE

Tags: c#, garbage-collection

I have three folders in my BIN directory.

1) Backlog
 2) InProgress
 3) Completed

There are TXT files in Backlog folder. I have used below code to copy files from "Backlog" to "InProgress" during some operation.

```
System.IO.File.Copy(source,target,true);
```

File succesfully copied to destination folder. now i want to delete the original file from "Backlog". so I have used below code.

```
System.IO.File.Delete(source);
```

It thorws exception, "Process can not access the file source..."

I think its issue with Garbage collection and I need to destroy this using "USING" statement. But i tried below, it says syntax for USING is wrong :(

```
using(System.IO.File.Copy(source,target,true)){}
```

I have tried below MOVE, but I still get same error.

```
using(System.IO.File.Move(source,target))
```

Note: MOVE is success during moving file from FOLDER 1 to FOLDER 2, 
      MOVE is FAILED during moving file from FOLDER 2 to FOLDER 3,

So I feel, after first MOVE, we have to reset something??

FULL CODE

```
string filepathBackLog = AppSettings["Backlog"];
string filepathInProgress = AppSettings["InProgress"];
string filepathCompleted = AppSettings["Completed"];

if(!System.IO.File.Exists(filepathBackLog ))
    return;

System.IO.File.Move(filepathBackLog ,filepathInProgress ); //Success, I can see it in folder.
System.IO.File.Move(filepathInProgress ,filepathCompleted );//Exception, I think we need to give some time to execute first MOVE.
```

Kindly guide me how can I resolve this?

Comment: `File.Copy` doesn't retain a file handle - once it returns, it's not responsible for keeping the file locked. Something else is, but it's in the code that you're not showing us. How/Where is `source`s value obtained?

Comment: I find it hard to believe that there's no code between those two `Move`s. And I'd be willing to bet that the code between those two `Move`s actually does something to *access* the file.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use [File.Move](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.move%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)? It will take care of deleting, too.

Comment: This is more like a *suggestion*, not a real answer. Because if `File.Delete` fails, then `File.Move` will fail too.

Comment: Well, not exactly. Moving a file doesn't actually copy and delete it. And there are number of reasons - beyond the code snippet - which may be blocking the deletion.

Comment: Please see EDITED contents

Comment: Are you still writing to your backlog at the point of copying?

Comment: No Marko, There is no write operation. Its single static file. no one writing anything to it.

Comment: What happens, if you move it directly from backlog to completed?